# Как получить id и ник цитируемого пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пользователь цитирует чье то сообщение в группе и пишет '+n'
Бот собирает id и ник цитируемого пользователя, парсит n (целое, натуральное число) и добавляет в бд.

Как получить значение n в переменную, чтобы использовать ее внутри функции ?
Не могу понять как получить id и ник цитируемого пользователя?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставил один вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем разобрался сам:

`message.reply_to_message.from_user.id`

- возвращает id пользователя цитируемого сообщения

`message.reply_to_message.from_user.username`

- возвращает ник пользователя цитируемого сообщения

Что касается проблемы +n:
Создал обработчик для любого сообщения начинающегося с +:

```
if message.text.startswith('+'):
pass
```

Дальше распарсил сообщение с помощью регулярок и исключений

Как-то так